# Gitlab CI unable to pick variables from project settings

Tags: azure, gitlab-ci

I am using the following yaml file where I declared all variables within the project settings. The AZ login command failed to run. When I replaced the variables with the actual value, it was able to run. Any idea why the variable values are not getting picked from the project settings ?

```
variables:
  DEFAULT_RG:
    description: "Default resource group to deploy the resources for testing"
    value: "newgrp"
  DEFAULT_LOCATION:
    description: "Default location of the testing resource group"
    value: "East US"
  
default:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
  before_script:
    - az login --service-principal --username $SP_ID --password $SP_SECRET --tenant $TENANT_ID
    - az account set --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    - set -euo pipefail

stages:
  - deploy
deploy automation account and tie it with UAMI:
  stage: deploy
   
  script:
    - New-AzAutomationAccount -Location $Location -Name $automationccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup
    - Set-AzAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $automationccount -AssignUserIdentity "/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourcegroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/$userAssignedOne"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out the issue. I had used all the variables as 'protected' which would mean that I can use these variables only on protected branches!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your variables type, if they are set to be protected; you can only access them from protected branches.

So, you either only `mask` them or update the protected branch list to include your current branch.

Comment: Thanks Kaish, that exactly was the issue!